# How to hide extjs grid column separator?

Tags: extjs, grid

I would like to hide the last column separator for an extjs grid.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `flex:1` to the last column in the grid it will stretch the remaining distance left in the grid then.

Here's a simple example:

```
Ext.define('App.view.exampleGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'exampleGrid',
    store: myStore,
    columns: [
            { header: 'field 1', dataIndex: 'field1' },
            { header: 'field 2', dataIndex: 'field2' ,flex:1},
    ]
});
```

**Edit 1:**

To remove the line you can override the style `border-width`, Create a custom css file and add the following (be sure to include this stylesheet in your index.html):

```
.RemoveLine
{
    border-width:0px !important;
}
```

Then, set the `cls` property of the last column:

```
columns: [{
        header: 'Column With Out Override',
        dataIndex: 'Column1'
    },  {
        header: 'Column With Override',
        dataIndex: 'Column2',
        cls:'RemoveLine'
    }]
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/480) demonstrating an example

Comment: This is only stretching the column which wasn't my question. I want to hide the last separator and not stretch the last column to cover the remaining area.

Comment: @Sofiane Let me see if i understand, you want to hide the ability to resize the column? Or are you trying to remove the visible line on the last column?

Comment: I want to remove the visible line in the last column header. Is that possible?

Comment: @Sofiane yeah it is, ill add to the answer, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Sofiane sorry for the delay, stack went read-only for a moment

Comment: it's not working but you gave a good idea about the solution which is the use of css. Thank's a lot.

Comment: cool, glad it helped.  Here is [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/480) demonstrating the working code if you still need it.